# prettyphoto is not working with links not loaded with the DOM

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

i'm having some images when clicking on any of them a medium size of the image appears and when clicking the medium size it should load the large size using pretty photo but afte clicking any of the small photos to load the medium image and clicking the ,edium image the prettyphoto doesn't work and the larger image opens as a link

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 

$(document).on("click",".image a",function(){
    var num = $(this).parent().index()+1;
    $(".bottom").slideUp(500,',function(){
        $(".bottom").html("<a rel='prettyPhoto' href='images/"+num+"_large.jpg'><img src='images/"+num+"_med.jpg'></a>").slideDown(500);    
    });
});

$("a[rel='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

html

```
<div class="container">

<div class="top">
<div class="image"><img src="images/1.jpg"  alt=""/></div>
<div class="image"><img src="images/2.jpg"  alt=""/></div>
<div class="image"><img src="images/3.jpg"  alt=""/></div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
<a href="images/1_large.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/1_med.jpg" width="640" height="480"  alt=""/></a>
</div>

</div>
```

full code to download http://www.mediafire.com/?xd97aonsjz3oyc0

and http://jsfiddle.net/frTAY/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. This is the correct code to use:

```
$(document).on("click",".image a",function(){
    var num = $(this).parent().index()+1;
    $(".bottom").slideUp(500,function(){
        $(".bottom").html("<a rel='prettyPhoto' href='images/"+num+"_large.jpg'><img src=images/"+num+"_med.jpg></a>").slideDown(500);  
    });
});
```